# Nivo Slide Transitions Not Working

Tags: nivo-slider

My Nivo slide transitions were working in an earlier iteration of this test page. But now I see they aren't working, the slides are no longer functioning as links to other pages like they should, and the captions are appearing about a second before the slide. I have gone over everything with a fine-toothed comb but obviously not fine enough.

The page in question is:
http://americanart.si.edu/index_new_prerelease_jeff2.cfm

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I scanned your HTML and Javascript and the only thing I can say is, you have an error on jTweetsAnywhere. It isn't uncommon that if one function, no matter where, gives an error, other stuff stops working too.
So try fixing that error first, or commenting out the jTweetsAnywhere initiation as it isn't recognised ("has no method 'jTweetsAnywhere'")